# Change Xcode to use custom-installed version of Subversion

Tags: svn, xcode

Does anyone know how to change the location of the svn tool used in the Xcode IDE?

I've installed a newer version in `/opt/subversion/bin` and updated my `$PATH` so that it works from the command line but can't get Xcode to recognize this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, Xcode hardcodes its Subversion paths to the `/usr/lib/` prefix. You can either symlink them ([as described over here](http://www.lemonteam.com/blog/2008/12/setting-up-subversion-15-on-xcode/)) or copy them ([cf. here](http://www.talentgrouplabs.com/blog/archive/2008/12/02/xcode-3.1.2-and-subversion-1.5.x-compatibility.aspx)).

Answer (score 1):

Applications in Mac OS X aren't run from a shell, so they won't have any knowledge of shell variables.  Just adding something to your `$PATH` in your `.bashrc` or `.cshrc` or whatever won't tell applications about it at all.

Furthermore, Xcode 3.0 and later support Subversion directly, rather than by calling through its command-line binary; this means that it will use the Subversion libraries in `/usr/lib` rather than any you've installed elsewhere.

Comment: hi, how can you link to the libarries that you installed from source? (i installed svn with macports)