# MacPort ports not overriding pre-installed older versions

Tags: macos, macports

I have XCode 3.2.6 which includes SVN 1.6.x. I just installed MacPorts and got subversion which is 1.7.x, but when I run `svn --version` it shows 1.6.17.

I installed MacPorts after Xcode, why is Scode#s version taking precedence?

Answer (score 5):

If you are running `svn` from a shell command line (like in a terminal window), you need to make sure that the `bin` directory where MacPorts installs things (the default is `/opt/local/bin`) comes before the location where the Apple-installed version is (`/usr/bin`).  This is controlled by the process environment variable `PATH`.

```
$ export PATH=/opt/local/bin/:$PATH
```

To make this change *permanent*, add the line to your shell startup file, for example, `.bash_profile`.

```
$ echo $PATH
/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11/bin
$ which svn
/usr/bin/svn$ svn --version
svn, version 1.6.17 (r1128011)
   compiled Feb  1 2012, 15:04:34
[...]
$ export PATH=/opt/local/bin:$PATH
$ echo $PATH
/opt/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11/bin
$ which svn
/opt/local/bin/svn
$ svn --version
svn, version 1.7.4 (r1295709)
   compiled Mar  8 2012, 19:29:25
[...]
```

Comment: I am running from Terminal, my PATH looks like this: `PATH="/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin`

Comment: What does `type -a svn` show?  What does `port installed | grep subversion` show?  What does `port contents subversion` show?

Comment: @KenThomases `subversion @1.7.4_0 (active)` from `port installed`. `port contents` displays loads of stuff all in `/opt/local/... `type -a svn` gives two lines: `svn is /opt/local/bin/svn`, `svn is /usr/bin/svn`

Comment: Are you asking how to get Xcode to use a newer version of subversion?  If so, the shell `PATH` environment variable has no effect on what Xcode uses.  See this question for one way to do that, but keep in mind that will overwrite Apple-supplied files, never a good idea:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/473977/change-xcode-to-use-custom-installed-version-of-subversion

Comment: @John, that all looks good.  What does `ls -l /opt/local/bin/svn` show? Also, what about `/opt/local/bin/svn --version`?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem (`svn --version` showed 1.6.x), even though `/opt/local/bin` was at the front of the path, and `which svn` returned `/opt/local/bin/svn`, and running `/opt/local/bin/svn --version` showed 1.7.x.

For me, restarting Terminal fixed it.

Comment: I've got the same problem with git (1.7 installed in /usr/bin/git by default and 1.8 in /opt/local/bin/git by macport) `type -a git` give me `git is /opt/local/bin/git` and `git is /usr/bin/git`, but the last one still executed. Relaunch Terminal (or maybe just the current bash session) will execute now the first one.